# @ConditionalOnBean not working with JdbcTemplate.class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some spring component:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnBean(value={JdbcTemplate.class})
public class DictionaryHandler implements Handler {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DictionaryHandler(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    //some methods
}
```

In debug, I see, that `JdbcTemplate` bean was created:
[image]

But, my bean not created.It doesn't go into the constructor. But why? Bean `JdbcTemplate` is exist, but my bean not created.

Does the condition work wrong? I don't want create `DictionaryHandler` if `JdbcTemplate` is missing. Without this I get an error.

Comment: Did `DictionaryHandler` created when you remove the conditional?

Comment: @AdhikaSetyaPramudita, Yes, `DictionaryHandler` was created succesfully

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`@ConditionalOnBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html) on auto configuration classes only (otherwise the order is unspecified)

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

Since your `JdbcTemplate` bean is defined inside `JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration` class so I  assume that `JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration` is marked with `@Configuration`.

In that case, you can ensure the instantiate of your bean by config:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration.class)
public class DicationaryHandlerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(JdbcTemplate.class)
    public DictionaryHandler handler(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
         return new DictionaryHandler(jdbcTemplate)
    }

}

public class DictionaryHandler implements Handler {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public DictionaryHandler(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    //some methods
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation for ConditionalOnBean. It runs once and if the bean it requires not yet created - it will not trigger. The order of bean creation matters. You can try to lower priority of your component with @Order annotation or increase priority of you configuration/component class which holds JdbcTemplate bean.

Answer (score 1):

From [Annotation Type ConditionalOnBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html):

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

In your case, the problem is `DictionaryHandler` bean is attempted to be created before processing the configuration class and given that `JdbcTemplate` bean is not yet in DI container, your `DictionaryHandler` is not getting instantiated.
One workaround could be to initialize `DictionaryHandler` in the same configuration class as `JdbcTemplate`.
Also, you can use different configuration class, but you'll have to use `@DependsOn` annotation.

An example:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "bean1")
class AnotherBean {
}

@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    public Object bean1() {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

In the previous example `AnotherBean` will not be created, but it will be in this way:

```
@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    public Object bean1() {
        return new Object();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(name = "bean1")
    public AnotherBean anotherBean() {
        return new AnotherBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell please, I can take out my beans like in the separate starter and already in it to use autoconfiguration? How to keep the business logic in the starters?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question, could you please clarify what do you mean by `take out my beans like in the separate starter and already in it to use autoconfiguration`?

Comment: I think what he means is: what if you have different modules (and configuration classes) and bring them all together as dependencies in a spring-starter? If that's not what he's asking, it's what I'm asking, because I'm having that exact problem. The two beans are in different dependencies, and I can't control the order they are loaded. DependsOn and Order annotations don't seem to be working. How can I guarantee the order if the two beans are in different configuration files (and different codebases altogether)?